# Контрол с поддержкой прозрачности Winfroms

Tags: winforms

Здравствуйте, уважаемые Господа.

Собственно говоря это не сколько вопрос, а сколько просьба о совете.

Сначала немного о том что я хочу сделать:
В программе, использующей Winforms, создать нечто вроде воркспейса, на который можно помещать изображения (любого формата - jpeg, gif, png...), при этом должно происходить смешивание по альфа-каналу. 
Собственно говоря нужно уже готовое решение (если таковое есть).
Может кто-нибудь что-нибдуь подсказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказываю, используйте [Google](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23%20control%20with%20transparent%20background&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.bGE&fp=8c70a7b1a326f205&biw=1613&bih=957&pf=p&pdl=300).

- [How to create a transparent control which works when on top of other controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592538/how-to-create-a-transparent-control-which-works-when-on-top-of-other-controls)
- [How do you allow transparent backgrounds on C# controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242984/how-do-you-allow-transparent-backgrounds-on-c-sharp-controls)
- [Making Transparent Controls - No Flickering](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26878/Making-Transparent-Controls-No-Flickering)

Comment: Все гениальное просто)